# Is it possible to disable default login pages in community?

Tags: community, lightning-community

When setting up Login & Registration pages in community, it's possible to select different page types.

[image]

Each of these type accessible by different URL:

- Login - Default  Page URL - https://domain.force.com/login
- Login - Community Builder Page URL -
  https://domain.force.com/s/login/

When a community is published and activated, **BOTH** URLs are active. That is when I go to this URL /login, it opens the default page. When I click this URL /s/login/, the community builder page is opened. What I need is when I select Community Builder Page as a page type for login, then default page should not be accessible. I have custom logic in the community builder page custom controller which prevents certain users from login. But if standard default page is alive, then users can simply bypass our custom validations. This is not good.

Is it possible to deactivate default page at all?

Comment: do you want to use a custom login page?

Comment: Yes, I want to use a custom login page only. But the problem is when I use, the default page is also accessible. This means that users have two separate pages for login. And since the default page is not customizable, I cannot add validations there to prevent certain users from signing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a URL Redirect from the default login page to your custom login page.  This can be found on the Site detail page, a button labeled "URL Redirects".  Create a new rule that puts a permanent redirect from `/login` to the desired login page.  Be aware that if your community has a custom URL path, then the Target URL may also need to include this path.

This won't deactivate the default page per se, but users won't be able to reach it.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the default  /s/login in the same way? It doesn't seem to work for me but it's working as charm with the /login

Comment: For my (lightning) community I have a modified login page as part of that lightning community and this is shown whether I access /login or /s/login. Can you use this approach instead? I didn't try actually disabling login entirely on the page, but you could give it a go...

Answer (score 0):

The above answer won't work in two situations:

1. If you have a configuration where users can SSO into your experience site via an external IdP.  The reason for this is that the ACS urls in salesforce start with "/login", so that redirect will break your SSO flow.
2. If you're using a custom VF page for your login page.  This is because the redirect will insert "/s" into your url, and the url for your custom login page won't have that /s in it.

I have opened a case with SF about this and been told:

"After double checking our documentation and doing a bit of research, it would not be possible to remove/delete the standard login page. The options to change the page are valid but as you discovered, someone directly editing their URL can workaround your default page setting."

I have also tried to modify the CommunitiesLanging page, CommunititesLandingController, CommunitiesLogin page, and CommunitiesLoginController to forward to my custom VF page directly, however I wasn't able to get that working either.

Unforatunately I don't have an answer for this issue as of yet.  I was going to leave all of this as a comment on the previous answer however I don't have 50 reputation, so I can't comment.

**UPDATE - solution if you have the same issue as above**

What I did was create a custom Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass where the "initiate" method does nothing but return a PageReference to "Network.getLoginUrl(networkId)" - networkId is [select Id from Network where Name = 'Your Exp Site']. Then you set up an Auth.Provider for it, and select only that option in the "Select login options to display…" config on the experience site. Then whenever someone hits that standard login page they get redirected to your custom VF login page that the site is configured to use.  It's a hack, but it works.

Comment: I am also having the issue you outlined above. By any chance, did you find a solution/workaround for this?

Comment: Yeah - what I did was create a custom Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass where the "initiate" method does nothing but return a PageReference to "Network.getLoginUrl(networkId)".  Then you set up an Auth.Provider for it, and select only that option in the "Select login options to display…" config on the experience site.  It's a hack, but it works.

Comment: Maybe I should add that to my answer so people are more likely to find it...